# Cannot retrieve and display images from mysql via php after upgrade to php7

Tags: php, mysql

I hope this question hasn't been posted/answered elsewhere. Searching didn't yield any satisfactory results so I am posting in the hope that someone will be able to help me out.

I used the code below to display images from mysql database. Used to work perfectly with php 5.6. Today I upgraded to php7 and I simply cannot get it to work.

Displays error message:

> Could not get data:.

Here is the code. Please help if you can. Will be highly appreciated.

```
    <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5';

mysqli_select_db('my_db');
$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, mysqli_NUM))
{
    echo "{$row[0]}". "<em>" . "({$row[1]})"."</em>"."<br>";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Thanx for all the helpful comments. I have edited my code. It now displays the path and image filename but not the image. (images/avatars/filename.jpg). Here is the revised code:

```
    mysqli_select_db($conn, 'my_db');
    $retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        echo "{$row[0]}". "<em>" . "({$row[1]})"."</em>"."<br>";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Hi guys. I managed to get it working. Thank you all for your assistance and patience. As suggested I changed to `echo "<img src='".$row['0']."'/>"."<br>";
        echo "{$row[1]}". "<em>" . "({$row[2]})"."</em>";`

Comment: Enable PHP errors so you can see what the actual issue is: `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);` - Perhaps something is awry in your MySQLi installation.

Comment: Did you update the mysql package, too? PHP7 uses a different package.

Comment: @ Blake. Thank you very much. Please see my edited code

Comment: You are using `mysqli_fetch_array()` after doing a `SELECT *` so we have ZERO idea what columns are returned and what is in any of the columns.. So helping becomes **all to much guesswork**

Comment: PS: Using `mysqli_fetch_array()` with `SELECT *` is quite dangerous. If someone alters the order of the columns in the database, you are likely to get different columns returned in `$row[0]` than you where when you tested this code. Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` then you get NAMED columns like `$row['id'] and $row['filename']`

Comment: Hi Blake. Sorry but my code actually has: SELECT profiles_avatar FROM col132mod_cck_store_form_profiles ORDER BY id LIMIT 5. The column is where the image is stored and looks like "images/avatars/filename.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the db Link and Query params swapped..

```
$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );
```

Should be

```
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
```

Comment: @ Duane Lortie. Thank you very much. Please see my edited code

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code.

- `mysqli_select_db('my_db')` requires a db connection as the first parameter.
- `mysqli_select_db($conn, 'my_db')`

However, you could have just as easily used all 4 parameters:

- `$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, 'my_db');`

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Then:

- `mysqli_error()` requires a parameter for it.
- `mysqli_error($conn)`

Then:

- `mysqli_query( $sql, $conn )` You need to inverse those, the connection must be first.
- `mysqli_query( $conn, $sql )`

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

And just to be certain, `table` if that's your real table name, is a MySQL reserved word:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

So wrap it with ticks

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5';
```

---

**Footnotes:**

Since `MYSQLI_NUM` is a constant in PHP, the `mysqli_NUM` may fail here, so you may need to make it all in uppercase `MYSQLI_NUM`.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php

**Additional notes:**

Your question's title holds *"Cannot retrieve and display images"*.

I don't see where you're wanting to display an image here, as there are no `<img>` tags.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

> *"Displays error message:*
>
> *Could not get data:"*

This tells me that either your PHP configuration is wrong, or you're accessing it as `file:///` rather than `http://localhost`.

Or, as I already outlined, `mysqli_error()` requires a db connection parameter where yours does not include it and is erroring out but you're not seeing the message it's throwing.

Use error reporting also and to catch and display:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

As Blake outlined in comments:

> *"Did you update the mysql package, too? PHP7 uses a different package."*

So, make sure your installation was successful and that all system files  were correctly updated and pointing to the right path/`.ini` file(s), and that you restarted all services and are running.

Consult ***Migrating from PHP 5.6.x to PHP 7.0.x***:

- http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

---

As stated by RiggsFolly in comments:

*"You are using `mysqli_fetch_array()` after doing a `SELECT *` so we have ZERO idea what columns are returned and what is in any of the columns."*

and...

*"PS: Using `mysqli_fetch_array()` with `SELECT *` is quite dangerous. If someone alters the order of the columns in the database, you are likely to get different columns returned in `$row[0]` than you where when you tested this code. Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` then you get NAMED columns like `$row['id']` and `$row['filename']`."*

I will say this again; you need to use `<img src...>` in order to show the images. Your code as shown, will not automagically show the images, that's what `<img>` is for.

Comment: @ Fred -ii-. Thank you very much. Please see my edited code

Comment: You're welcome. Thing is, am mobile right now for about an hour so am limited for certain things. In order to show images, you need the <img> tag as described in my answer and to be sure the path(s) is correct.

Comment: I.e: <img src="$row[0]"> type of thing. You will need to play around with this since as I said that I am limited to doing certain things on mobile. Try that and keep me posted, I'll be back on my workstation later.

Comment: You do give Good, Comprehensive Answers, even when mobile

Comment: *Thank you squire* @RiggsFolly I'm on my workstation now ;-) Now I can do *"Fancy pants"* stuff just like you now ;-)

Comment: Welcome to the _Fancy Pant Crew_ my brother

Comment: You might want to add a bit about `SELECT *` and `mysqli_fetch_array()` to this answer, see my comments above

Comment: @RiggsFolly I noticed your comment(s) earlier and added the last one you put under the OP's question and just added the other one now; thanks again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you used to use mysql_*() functions in the previous php version and changed to mysqli when you upgraded to php7.

Although mysqli can be used very similarly to the mysql extension, there are subtle differences.

1. You can select the default db when you create the connection.
2. The connection and query parameters are reversed in mysqli_query().

There are other differences as well, so pls read the documentation before adding a letter `i` to the mysql_*() functions!

Comment: @ Shadow. Thank you very much. Please see my edited code